# What is the proper algo/method to track changes between two async calls/requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, websocket

I have frontend that send requests to backend to keep the data as "live" as possible. The problem is that if frontend sends two different(in terms of data) requests in a short period of time, server may get the second request before the first one(due to delay, bad network, async etc).

My question is there any type of algorithm/method to deal with such events, to track changes in a sync way for async requests?

I thought of timestamps, but in that case I would need to "trust" the client - doesn't look a good solution.

I can't share my code(not sure if it's going to help anyway) or give you exactly what I'm making, but it's kind of live-text-editor, when two(or more) parties can see the editor and make changes to it.

Also, even though I would prefer not to use web-sockets, but perhaps web-sockets could solve this problem(never used it before)? I don't know how web-sockets work especially with asynchronous calls.

I use MERN stack, in case it's relevant.

Comment: Can there be multiple frontends (for example, different people each sitting in front of their own browser) connected to your backend concurrently? Or is there just one frontend and one backend?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Yes, of course it's about multi-client interaction, so multiple frontends. In terms of concurrency, at the moment I'm pinging server from the client to check if there's new data available for him. But, as I said in the post, I'm ok with switching to whatever is needed(web-sockets etc), if that would do the trick, but would really appreciate an alternative as well.

Comment: "For him" - so every client has its own data? In that case, can't the client simply wait with a new request until it has received the previous response?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Imagine there's a live-text-editor for me and you. I type "h" and request is fired to the server, but then I type "e", "l", "l", "o" and for each of the letters corresponding request is fired to notify the server about the change. This is silly example, but it illustrate the problem I'm facing. While I want to send "hello", you may receive something like "helol". I also can't sacrifice performance/responsiveness of the app by waiting a response back each request the client send.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen And of course I'm aware of debounce/throttle, but it's more complex than that. Please take the above example with live-text-editor as example of the problem, nothing more.

Comment: `I thought of timestamps, but in that case I would need to "trust" the client - doesn't look a good solution.` - You have to trust the client with the data, so why can't you trust the client with a timestamp, or even simpler a sequential number...?  With a timestamp you don't know that a packet was missed, but with a sequential number, the server side will know that a packet was missed, and can then queue the current packets until the next expected sequence number arrives...